# Parse Push notification app crash

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, crash

Im trying to implement push notification using parse but my app crash
 even before any app delegate any method call for testing device is iPod touch is that cause problem ? my log output as below

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSURLComponents
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/576604A9-F5B4-4DF1-B8AA-D71E81C09E17/PushDemo.app/PushDemo
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
 in /var/mobile/Applications/576604A9-F5B4-4DF1-B8AA-D71E81C09E17/PushDemo.app/PushDemo
(lldb)
```